Running game on cloud windows instance
I have a discord bot that integrates with a game called rise of kingdoms, I want to run the bot 24/7 but I don't know where to get a cheap windows instance that can run a game like rise of kingdoms for the bot to operate,
can anyone guide me ? my budget is 5-10 dollars per month for the machine
I tried aws and google cloud but it seems that I need machine with graphics to properly run the game
